# Render loop vs. explicitely calling update method

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering

I am working on a 3D simulation program using openGL which uses a render loop with a fixed framerate to keep the screen updated as the world changes. Standard procedure really, and for a typical video game this is certainly the best approach (I originally took this code from an openGL game tutorial). But for me, the 3D scene will not be changing as rapidly and unpredictably as in a computer game. It will be possible for the 3D scene itself to change from time to time but in general it won't change between render calls (it's more of a visualisation tool for geometric problems). The user will be able to control the position/orientation of the camera but in general there will be times when the camera won't move for several seconds/minutes (potentially hundreds of render calls) and since the 3D scene is likely be static for the majority of the time, I wonder if I really need a continuous render loop...?

My thinking is that I will remove the automatic render loop and instead I will explicitly call my *update* method when either,

1. The 3D scene changes (very rare)
2. The camera moves (somewhat rare)

As I will be using this largely for research purposes, the scene/camera is likely to stay in one state for several minutes at a time and it seems silly to be continuously updating the frame buffer when it's not changing.

My question then is, is this a good approach? All the online tutorials for 3D graphics rendering seem to deal with game design but that's not really my requirement. In other words, what are the pros and cons of using a render loop vs. manually calling "update()" whenever something changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with this approach, in fact many 3D apps, like 3DS MAX use explicit rendering. You just pick what is better for your needs, in most games scene changes each frame so it's better to have update loop, but if you were doing some chess game, without animated UI you could also use explicit rendering only when the scene changes.

For apps with rare changes, like 3DS or Blender it would be better to call rendering only on change. This way you save the CPU/GPU but also power and your PC don't heat up so much.

With explicit rendering you can also have some performance tricks, like drawing simplified scene when camera moves, for better performance. Then when camera stops you render the full scene in background once again, and replace the low-quality rendering with the new one.